# Force number input to have two decimal places and always show two decimals in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to have an input field that always limits input to two decimal places but also displays two decimal places,

I know this is a follow on to this question:

[Force number input to have two decimal places and ONLY two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543817/force-number-input-to-have-two-decimal-places-and-only-two][1])

But when I implement this in React, it doesn't format to 2 decimal places, if say the number is 3. It is as if it is ignoring the step prop.

Comment: Does it work when you enter something like 3.14159 ? Do you use firefox? Firefox does cut off the zeros with toFixed https://www.zigpress.com/2016/12/05/javascript-tofixed-does-not-work-in-number-fields-on-firefox/

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a working example for chrome here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/xo2x1qnw0w

For Firefox the *.toFixed()* method is not properly working as it cuts off the non-significant zeroes. It does work however for numbers like *42.98763*

Comment: This all works really well. Thank you. Now however, when I integrate it with react-redux-form i have a problem that the cursor is always thrown to the back, if one updates the fractional part. I will look to see if I can get a demo going to show this.

Comment: Not good enough, since it doesnt support editing while giving input

Answer (score 1):

This is my money input solution.. it doesn't force two decimal places until more than 2 decimal places are typed in, as that makes it hard for the user to type:

```
import { useRef } from 'react'

function handleMoneyChange(e){
    if(e.key !== "Backspace"){
        if(offerAmtRef.current.value.includes('.')){
            if(offerAmtRef.current.value.split('.')[1].length >= 2){
                var num = parseFloat(offerAmtRef.current.value);
                var cleanNum = num.toFixed(2);
                offerAmtRef.current.value = cleanNum;
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
}

<input
    type="number"
    step=".01"
    ref={offerAmtRef}
    defaultValue={offerAmtRef.current}
    onKeyDown={(e)=> {
        handleMoneyChange(e)
    }}
/>
```

Comment: This one works especially well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like

```
const handleChange = (evt) => {
  const { value } = evt.target;

  // check if value includes a decimal point
  if (value.match(/\./g)) {
    const [, decimal] = value.split('.');

    // restrict value to only 2 decimal places
    if (decimal?.length > 2) {
      // do nothing
      return;
    }
  }

  // otherwise, update value in state
  setPrice(value);
}

<input type="number" value={price} onChange={handleChange} />
```