# Restrict input to 5 characters if whole number or 8 characters with fraction

Tags: javascript, input, maxlength

I have simple text input:

```
 <div style="float:right" class="xField">
      <input id="userLength" name="userLength"/>
      <label style="margin-left: 3px;">m</label>
 </div>
```

I need this input to only accept numbers and if the number is a whole number, it should only allow 5 characters i.e. `12345`. If the number includes a fraction, it should then allow for 8 characters i.e. `12345,99`.

I've tried adding `maxlength` to the input but that only works with one of these conditions at a time.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force number input to have two decimal places and ONLY two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543817/force-number-input-to-have-two-decimal-places-and-only-two)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefpattern) attribute and provide a regular expression that supports your requirements.

for example (*this does not forbid entering invalid data, but will mark the field as invalid while the pattern is not matched*).

```html
<div style="float:right" class="xField">
      <input id="userLength" name="userLength" pattern="\d{1,5}(,\d{1,2})?" />
      <label style="margin-left: 3px;">m</label>
 </div>
```

Comment: This allows the user to enter whatever they want, and marks the input as invalid if the value doesn't match the pattern.

Comment: @HereticMonkey that is the recommendation. What if the user is pasting from a document and wants to edit before submitting? it is rude to disallow pasting altogether. Best to leave the validation for when the user explicitly submits

Comment: @santiagoarizti Sure, and if the answer gave that caveat, I wouldn't have added my comment. As it is, the answer is presented as an answer to the question of how to restrict the user from entering more than five numbers and two decimals.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is this:

```
<form action="/" id="form">
    <input pattern="\d{0,5}([,.]\d{1,2})?" title="max 5 digits and 2 decimals">
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

This will allow the user to enter as many characters as he wishes, but upon form validation the form will fail if the **pattern** is not satisfied.

The pattern is a regex and reads as follows: *from 0 to 5 numeric characters and optionally up to two decimals*

Also, if the input should not be empty you can add a **required** attribute like this

```
<input ... pattern="" required>
```

This causes also a validation failure if the input is empty.

When the pattern is not met, the browser will show whatever is inside `title=""` to the user.

Play around with this fiddle so you can see how the validation errors are presented: https://jsfiddle.net/aqohfsrj/2/

Also, if you want to do something with the input value using javascript, I recommend binding to the form's **submit** event and not the button's click or input's enter-keydown events

```
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", e => {
    // if this code is executed it means the validation passed, otherwise errors
    // are displayed to the user and this code is not run.
    e.preventDefault(); // <-- to avoid trying to use the form's action i.e. the browser will not navigate.
});
```

To understand the regex I used you can see this regex101 file: 
https://regex101.com/r/aHLI6u/1

Finally a recommendation:
Try to avoid `maxlength` **for validation**; often times I have had to fill in a form online that asks for a credit card for example, and it is limited to `maxlength="16"` which at first sounds like a good idea, but what if you try to copy your credit card from a note you have or something, and it was stored as `5430-0000-1111-2222` (with dashes). It feels rude to disallow pasting more chars than allowed, when all the user wanted was to paste, then edit, then submit. I would let the user add as much content as they want, so they can edit in-place to remove parentheses (for phones), remove currency signs (for money), remove dashes (for credit cards) and validate **after** they have submitted the form.

Comment: if you feel overwhelmed by regular expresions (regex) you can google for almost all types of regexes that people has shared and perfected overtime. For example, to validate an email address or currency it is best to use a regex that has been tried-and-tested by others. My regex was written by myself just now and I don't know if it satisfies all your needs